# There are 5,931 questions tagged both elementary-number-theory and number-theory

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

([Prompted by this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17544/about-probability-theory-tag))

As you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-number-theory+number-theory), there are (as of January 2020) 5,931 questions tagged [elementary-number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-number-theory) and [number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory). (For the record, there are respectively 28,327 and 31,874 questions in these tags, so that's not insignificant).

It's always been my impression that these sort of tags are mutually exclusive: [set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-theory) vs [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory), [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) vs [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus), [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability) vs [probability-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-theory), etc. In any case it makes zero sense for a question to have both tags, it's just redundant; they can always be tagged just [elementary-number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-number-theory).

I believe the differentiation between [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) and [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) works because they are names of actual classes in standard curriculums in the US, and there are very active users (user?) dealing with set theory questions. However, things didn't work out so well for probability theory, as we can see in the question I linked at the top, and number theory is going the same way.

Rather than dealing with specific cases, I'd like to ask general questions:

- Is differentiating tags by level useful?
- Is differentiating tags by level feasible? How?
- How to decide when a tag needs to be split like this? How to decide what the threshold should?

Comment: Yeah, we dealt with this mess (although on a much smaller scale) with a large intersection of set theory and elementary set theory.

Comment: In the case of set theory the tag info does the good job. If you look at the tag-info for [elementary-set-theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/elementary-set-theory/info) and [set-theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/set-theory/info) you will see that a list of topics which are covered by the tag. Of course, the lists are not exhaustive, but they cover a lot of questions and help to decide which tag to use.

Comment: I have noticed this, too. I occasionally hunt these down, and edit the tags. My conservative estimate (no actual data I'm afraid) is that in 90% of the cases I either removed the NT tag, or replaced it with ENT. The rule of thumb is that if I can answer the question without rubbing the three grey cells together real hard it is ENT. Not foolproof, and the algorithm is still evolving

Comment: @Martin I doubt it's the tag wiki. Look at the case of probability: it's explained right in the tag excerpt what tag covers what, people still confuse the two.

Comment: New users frequently tag their question NT, because they learned about the material in a course titled (Intro to) NT. If we could make them actually read the tag excerpts, the problem would disappear. Not holding my breath.

Comment: Two  unrelated points: .) If elementary-number-theory is intended only as  "low level number theory" than elementary-number-theory is not a good name. .) I do not see the issue with redundancy in itself. Is is also a problem if something is tagged analytic-number-theory and number-theory? This is inherent to the tagging system.

Comment: @quid Regarding redundancy, I guess I could have said that better: [tag:number-theory] is explicitly for higher level than [tag:elementary-number-theory]. I assume users ask elementary questions then add both tags because they both seem to apply, but they don't. You're right that redundancy is not the right word, what I mean is that if elementary-number-theory can apply (and OP thought so by tagging the question that way), number-theory cannot apply. It's different from, say, tagging a question homotopy-theory and algebraic-topology.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi What I meant is that in the case of the two set theory tags, the tag-info does a good job in explaining what belongs to which tag. (The other question is whether the users actually apply the tags correctly.) In the case of number theory, the tag-wikis for [elementary-number-theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/22238/revisions) and [number-theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/22236/revisions) are more-or-less identical. So they do not help much when deciding which tag to choose.

Comment: I will just mention that also elementary-general-topology tag [was discussed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/elementary-general-topology-tag). [This older post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/sophistication-level-tags) is also to some extent related to the general questions asked at the end of your post.

Comment: As @Martin mentions, such issues have been raised before. Tagging questions with "sophistication" leads to various problems, e.g. in the thread Martin cites see [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/2090/242) *and* its comments. As in the example linked there, questions often receive answers of various levels of sophistication - which is pedagogically desirable since it often motivates students and plants in mind seeds of important generalizations that they will later need. It would help to have the ability to tag the level of the *answer*.

Comment: @Bill And yet the issues are still there, a significant number of number theory questions are mistagged, and it's even worse for probability. Rather than dealing with the issues on a case by case basis, it would be nice to have a discussion on how to prevent them from happening again: giving proper names to split tags, having a clear policy on what belongs to where...

Comment: [cont] I dislike the idea of meta "sophistication" tags (or meta tags at all) And I don't believe I'm talking about sophistication in this thread: this seems to apply to answers, not questions. Even if it's possible to answer an elementary question with a great amount of sophistication using very advanced notions, it still remains an elementary question.

Comment: @Martin (Part of my previous comments addresses one link you cited) As for the tag wikis, I think my point is that I don't believe people read tag wikis at all, and hardly read tag excerpts (example: probability tags have descriptive tag wikis/excerpts, but the situation is even worse than for number theory). I don't think it's the deciding factor (tag *names* seem more important than anything), and I think the concerted effort mentioned by Asaf earlier has been more decisive in the relative cleanliness of set theory related tags. Of course cleaning up the tag wikis would be important too.

Comment: @Najib No doubt there are many limitations of the current SE tag system. Fixing them would eliminate many of the problems here, e.g. allowing users to *precisely* filter out question that they don't like, whether they be too "PSQ", too elementary, too applied, etc. Rather than making kludgy patches, I think we should strive to develop a much more powerful tag system that would allow users to very precisely filter site content. This would go a long way towards attracting (and retaining) further expertise - which has always been one of the great challenges of the site.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I think the tag-wikis and tag-excerpt are important. There are people who do retag questions and try to keep questions correctly tagged. But if somebody wants to help with correct tagging, they have to know what belongs into which tag. If this is not clear, the place to go is to look in the tag info or check whether there was a discussion on meta.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes of course, you're right, that's not what I'm saying. Fixing the tag wiki is important. But I believe that it would be great if the need for retagging questions was alleviated by having users tagging them correctly in the first place, and it seems to me that the tag name is more important in that respect than the tag wiki.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Maybe you could go to the chat instead, and invite others. I guess there are too many comments on a question that's just a day old.

Comment: @Najib I was under the impression that "elementary number theory" is number theory other than "algebraic number theory" or "analytic number theory." So no imaginary numbers, no algebraic integers, no asymptotics or heuristics.

Comment: @RobertSoupe it's true that Elementary Number Theory is actually a technical term which pertains to specific topics, which is different from the case with, say, set theory (at least as far as I understand set theory). Certainly elementary number theory is an area of active research, which should indicate the tag is being misapplied more than anything. A more ideal solution would be to allow both tags or--if users just cannot get past using "elementary" for easy things--deleting the elementary tag altogether.

Comment: @BillDubuque just from a number theorist's perspective, since I like things meaning what I think they mean, leaving [tag:number-theory] and fixing the wiki for [tag:elementary-number-theory] and making sure all the topics are appropriately tagged is all I would expect. I don't come to MSE for things in elementary NT which are necessarily at a higher level. If a tag change were deemed absolutely necessary, I think for those of us in the area who feel as I do, something like "basic number theory" would be superior than messing with something that already has a meaning.

Comment: And in general, I think changing to a local definition such as "elementary" as "easy" will put things at a cross purpose. Redefining things which already have widely accepted--perhaps not by many of those asking the question, but for those with the expertise--meanings seems counterproductive.

Comment: @Adam I have always been an advocate of (much) stronger filtering tools. One should be able to filter questions by many criteria, e.g.  field, level, question-style ("work and/or context shown"), etc.

Comment: @BillDubuque if it weren't for the accursed 5 tag limit, I'd advocate strongly for a "basic" and "advanced" tag (or more robust ones) so that topics could have categorical tags for the subject and separate ones for the level. I don't know enough about the SE team to know if that's a feasible possibility. Perhaps as something aside from tags?

Comment: @URL Please don't make useless edits like this.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I re-prompted an unanswered question. How is that useless?

Comment: @URL The question was already bumped from the two answers.

Comment: If askers do not distinguish [tag:number-theory] and [tag:elementary-number-theory] tags, the tags should be merged; as simple as that, and the argument that nonetheless the tags *must* (why?) be distinct is just stubbornness, because the distinction does not work in practice.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that, although most of the times only one of the tags should be used, there are situations where both are appropriate. Consider, for example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996120/are-14-and-21-the-only-interesting-numbers) highly upvoted question. OP asks a question involving only prime numbers and elementary arithmetic:

> **Definition:** A positive integer $n$ is called ***interesting*** if it has a prime factorisation $n=pq$ with $p\ne q$ such that the prime factorisation of $n+1$ is $p'q'$ where $p'$ is the prime after $p$ and $q'$ the prime before $q$.
>
> Are there other interesting numbers [other than $14$ and $21$]?

However, [the only answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1996173/718671) makes use of the highly non-trivial and non-elementary result that, for $n\geq25$, there's always a prime between $n$ and $\frac65n$. Given the fact that nobody else bothered answering, it doesn't seem like the problem can be solved in any substantially simpler way.

I believe that, if a question (and its answers) might make use of both elementary and advanced concepts, using both tags should be appropriate.